# Ajax before HTML form submission (asynchronously)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

```
<form target="_blank" method="POST" action="somePage.php" id="myForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="someName" value="toBeAssignedLater"/>
  <button type="submit">Proceed</button>
</form>
```

At the beginning, the value of `someName` is not determined yet, I want to execute an Ajax to get and assign the value to it before the form is actually submitted.

I tried:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function (e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  someAjaxFunction(function (data) {
    $this.find('input[name="someName"]').val(data.value);
  });
});
```

But the form would have already submitted before the Ajax is finished, how can I ensure the form would be submitted after the Ajax is finished.

I want to keep the form `submit` event initiated by the user instead of code, such as `$("#myForm").trigger('submit');`, since I don't want the new window tab to be blocked by browsers.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#myForm").submit(function (e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  someAjaxFunction(function (data) {
    $this.find('input[name="someName"]').val(data.value);
    // submit form without triggering jquery handler
    $this[0].submit(); 
  });
  // cancel the current submission
  return false;
});
```

Comment: `$this[0].submit();` would lead to new window blocked by browsers, I think new window would not be block only if the event is triggered by user, such as mouse click on submit button.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you ajax the value at page load and than submit the data?

```
$(function(){
     someAjaxFunction(function (data) {
        $('input[name="someName"]').val(data.value);
      });
    $("#myForm button").on('click',function(){
      $(this).submit(); 
    });
    });
```

or place the ajax call on click event and submit whan the values is updated:

```
$(function(){

        $("#myForm button").on('click',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            url:url, //other params
            success:function(data){
                //thing to do before submit
               $('input[name="someName"]').val(data.value);
              $(this).submit(); 
            }
          });

        });
        });
```

Comment: Because there is something I would do in `someAjaxFunction`, and it should be done just before the form submission.